# Aligning Checkboxes in HTML that are not inline

Tags: html, css, alignment, row

I'm trying to get my checkboxes all in one row. For some reason they are in a column.

Here's a photo of what's going on: [image]

I need help aligning the checkboxes in a row instead of a column.

```css
.lowerToppings
{
  display: flex;

  justify-content: space-around;

}

.LowerToppingsCheckBoxes{
 display: inline-block;
   display: -moz-inline-box;
   *display: inline;
   zoom: 2; 
   width: 10%;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="lowerToppings">
  <img src="olivee.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  <img src="onion.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  <img src="bellpepper.jpg" width="100" height="100">
  </div>

  <br></br>

  <div class="LowerToppingsCheckBoxes">
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="cheese" name="toppings" value="cheese"></div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="toppings" value="pepperoni"></div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="mushroom" name="toppings" value="mushroom"></div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="pepper" name="toppings" value="pepper"></div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" id="basil" name="toppings" value="basil"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you set css .LowerToppingsCheckBoxes div{display:inline-block;}

Answer (score 0):

```css
.lowerToppings
{
    display: flex;

    justify-content: space-around;

}

.LowerToppingsCheckBoxes{
   display: inline-block;
   display: -moz-inline-box;
   *display: inline;
   zoom: 2; 
   width: 200px;
   text-align: center;
}
.LowerToppingsCheckBoxes div{display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="lowerToppings">
    <img src="olivee.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    <img src="onion.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    <img src="bellpepper.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </div>

    <br></br>

    <div class="LowerToppingsCheckBoxes">
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="cheese" name="toppings" value="cheese"></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="toppings" value="pepperoni"></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="mushroom" name="toppings" value="mushroom"></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="pepper" name="toppings" value="pepper"></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="basil" name="toppings" value="basil"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="LowerToppingsCheckBoxes">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cheese" name="toppings" value="cheese">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pepperoni" name="toppings" value="pepperoni">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mushroom" name="toppings" value="mushroom">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pepper" name="toppings" value="pepper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="basil" name="toppings" value="basil">
</div>

.LowerToppingsCheckBoxes{
  ...
  flex-direction: row; // add this
}
```

You may increase the width of the container in order to fit all the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display of .LowerToppingsCheckBoxes to flex it will arrange you checkbox in row

```css
.LowerToppingsCheckBoxes{
   display: flex;
   display: -moz-inline-box;
   zoom: 2;
   width: 10%;
   text-align: center;
}
```